# How to convert Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (i386) laptop into wifi hotspot?

Tags: hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I have wired Internet connection and want to connect my windows LUMIA for wifi.
I tried so many methods but none worked. Does it requires any driver or repository?
How can I check?
Laptop is Inspiron n4010 32-bit Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, see here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html

> **Create a wireless hotspot**
>
> You can use your computer as a wireless hotspot. This allows other devices to connect to you without a separate network, and allows you to share an internet connection you've made with another interface, such as to a wired network or over the cellular network.
>
> Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
>
> Open Network and select Wireless on the left.
>
> Click the Use as Hotspot button.
>
> If you are already connected to a wireless network, you will be asked if you want to disconnect from that network. A single wireless adapter can only connect to or create one network at a time. Click Create Hotspot to confirm.
> `